# Why is so much less RAM being used by 3DS Max in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory

I'm rendering stuff in 3dsMax. It's taking forever (progress bar is moving ahead...but I really think hours and hours for rendering sample underwater shows something went bad.)

I have 68 tabs open in Firefox.

I have other app's open too.

System is lagging, and I wanted to see how much RAM is being used, and I couldn't believe so little was being used. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit on a i7 system.

[image: Task Manager Performance]

Comment: is 3dsMax 64 bit?

Comment: @Keltari, I think it is. How do I make sure?

Comment: Whatever you're doing looks like it's CPU bound, are you absolutely certain it's 64bit windows 7?

Comment: @progtick, not sure.  probably in help/about.  if its not 64 bit, its not going to use more than 2GB of memory.

Comment: 32-bit windows can use a bit over 3G of main memory, but as Windows reports 12G on the task manager ("total" row), it for sure is 64-bit.

Comment: @Keltari, that's exactly where I looked.  I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: I know that's the case in XP but I thought win 7 recognised it all but couldn't address it.

Comment: 3ds Max is 64 bit... I just verified.

Comment: open task manager, 32-bit processes will have a "*" beside them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm rendering stuff in 3dsMax

3dsMax uses **CPU for rendering**, not memory, that's why you see so little Ram being used.
Your system is lagging because 3dsMax is using all 8 cpu's, that's good, otherwise it would take ages to render...
I guess you should let it render during the night when you're not using the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Click the Processes tab see why. 68 tabs are not important, if these are not memory hungry pages. About rendering; render uses CPU aggressively  and creates 2D graphics, however it uses memory step by step during this time.

Comment: what do you mean step by step?

Comment: It only uses required RAM to create 2D graphics, not for the entire universe. So rendering size in pixel and model complexity in the "viewport" matter. When it completes a frame, it releases the ram and skip to next frame.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into CPU, not RAM.

> I have 68 tabs open in Firefox.

That's... *A lot*! My guess is that it's possible that Firefox is slowing down your 3DS Max Rendering.

So, look into the CPU usage of the different processes.

Comment: I did close firefox by end-tasking it in task manager a few times during the rendering. I got bored and then reopened it.  What exactly should I be looking in CPU?

Comment: @progtick: See which processes have the most CPU (next to 3DS Max).